# Making PUT and GET Responses in Katalon Studio

Tags: api, get, put, restful-url, katalon-studio

I’m new in working with RESTful APIs. For my case I want to make an PUT Request and then GET it.

I made an PUT Request and it worked. [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4nZf.jpg

But now I want to make an GET Request. Can I somehow make so that GET Request will automatically take PUT Requests statementId and bind it to the link. [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wng7.jpg

I watched a lot of videos and documentations about APIs but still doens't get it how to make it. I’m really new for making such things and sorry if I asked a dumb question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found an answer:

RequestObject ro = findTestObject("GET_request")
ro.setRestUrl(String.format(ro.getRestUrl(), idValue2))

ResponseObject resp = WS.sendRequest(ro)

Answer (score 2):

These steps might help to solve your case:
 - Execute the PUT request
 - Get the Response, parse it using Jsonslurper, and the the value out.
 - Save the value into a variable, ie GlobalVariable
 - Create the GET request with parameter taken from the GlobalVariable
 - Execute the GET request.

Comment: Hey, how can I define new globalvariable ? String idValue2 = parsedJson.get('statementId') I made that and now I think that idValue2 must be global variable yes ? to use it in GET Request

Comment: You can create a new variable in the Profile manually, ie id. Then use GlobalVariable.id = <new value>

Comment: Okay, I'll try that.

Comment: in the profile, there is no global variable value type. I created string and used GlobalVariable.id = idVersion2 but it doesnt work

Comment: In the profile, they are all global variable https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/variable-types.html#global-variables

Comment: Can I show you my code ?  I think that I did everything good, but it doesnt working

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Mh3svfv , https://imgur.com/a/1lduIcG , https://imgur.com/a/iKzZUUm